# How to Move App's Data

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

As you can see here, i have already move the app to sd storage.

the problem is, my app data still using my root directory.

How to move my data to SD Storage Data???

Comment: You might want to take a look at our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), which gives some hints. A warning in advance: you cannot move your apps' data unless your device is rooted (or the app itself offers this).